# Confused about region of convergence in $z$ transform.

Tags: convergence-divergence, signal-processing

If $X_1(z)=\dfrac{z}{z-2}$  and $X_2(z)=\dfrac{z}{z+2},$
then what will be the difference between ROCs of $X_1$ and $X_2?$

Comment: Radius of convergence of what series or sequence are you looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have
\begin{align*}
X_1(z)&=\frac{1}{1-2z^{-1}}\\
X_2(z)&=\frac{1}{1+2z^{-1}}.
\end{align*}
From the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Region_of_convergence), we can see that the ROC for $X_1$ is $|z|>|2|,$ or $|z|>2.$ But we can rewrite $X_2$ as
$$X_2(z)=\frac{1}{1-(-2)z^{-1}}, $$
which we can see will have an identical ROC.